# Pin does not Detect All Dynamic Allocations

Tags: valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, trace, intel-pin

I wrote a really simple `Pin` tool to calculate the number of dynamically allocated bytes in a program. I instrumented `GIMP` with this tool and it reported `77 MB` of allocations. I did the same experiment with `Valgrind` which reported `117 MB`.

My `Pin` tool is similar to the example in `Pin`. It searches for `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `memalign()` in each loaded image and adds instructions before them to calculate the total size of the allocations. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> It searches for malloc(), calloc() and memalign()

There are other heap allocation functions you may not be intercepting and accounting for: `realloc` and `posix_memalign`.

You also need to keep track of all allocated pointers and intercept `free`, otherwise your counts are likely to be too high.

Comment: I checked for `realloc()` when tracing `GIMP` by `Valgrind`. Based on the top 10000 allocations (backtrace ordered by total allocation size), it finally boils down to `malloc()` (i.e., implemented by `malloc()`). By `memalign()` I mean `posix_memalign()`.

Comment: P.S. I also used another tool, called `heaptrack`. The result was even larger, `153MB`!!!https://github.com/KDAB/heaptrack

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for all of the following macros:

```
#define MMAP    "mmap"
#define REALLOC "realloc"
#define CALLOC  "calloc"
#define MALLOC  "malloc"
#define SBRK    "sbrk"
#define FREE    "free"
```

Capture the above allocations and check the allocation size.

Comment: AFAIK, `mmap()` is called by `malloc()` and not all calls to `mmap()` are allocations of dynamic variables. I think that `sbrk()` and `free()` only change the heap boundary and allow potentially (not actually) more subsequent allocations to take place.

Comment: An application can simply call `sbrk()` and use the entire allocated virtual memory range, bypassing malloc functions. It may use a custom allocation interface with that, eg je_malloc. The malloc functions can also be inlined. In other words, no wonder your approach doesn't work.